# Shift in Chrome with static background image

Tags: html, css

morning,

Question regarding layout shift in Chrome with background image.

Page is: http://tcia.org/TCIExpo/2017_Attendees/TCIExpo/Attendees/2017_Attendees.aspx

Fixed full width page background shifts slightly as if it is resizing, width-wise, when loading new page but only in Chrome. FF, IE is fine.

I've tried everything I could find far as adding to/altering CSS goes but no luck.

CSS:

```
body 
{
font-size: 17px;
background: url(https://www.tcia.org/images/TCIExpo/backgrounds/back-a3.jpg)
top  center  no-repeat;background-attachment: fixed;            
background-color: #aaba59;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
}
```

I'd really appreciate suggestions. Thank you.

Bob H

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of the problem you're seeing?

Comment: Try adjusting `background-size` property

Comment: Thank you for your help. I looked into background-size and added:     -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

Comment: Thank you for your help. I looked into background-size and added:     -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;    I also tried background-size: contain but no luck with either. The screenshot probably wouldn't be too useful  as it is a matter of background shifting to accommodate (it seems) the content container as it loads. If you might take a look at the url it might make more sense, if you don't mind. Again, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: This fixed the repositioning issue per above: background-position: inherit;
background-position: initial;
background-position: unset; Thanks again for helping me, guys

Comment: I spoke too soon...this fix that I came up with regarding background: position did not fix my position hiccup. More suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.